# CSS Design: Help placing diagonal columns to fill screen from top-right

Tags: css, multiple-columns, css-transforms, diagonal, css-gradients

Good Evening,

I am currently trying to design a diagonal column effect on a new website I am developing, but am having trouble trying to place the background correctly.

[An image of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb3rn.png).

Ideally I would then like to change the colours based on a scroll event and/or some animation, which is why I am trying to achieve this effect with CSS and not using a mocked-up image for the background. The website will need to be made responsive, which removes some hardcoded possibilities..

[Here is a CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0y74r7x1z) containing an attempt I have made at trying to solve this issue.. The transform-origin property unfortunately does not seem to work as intended.

EDIT: Adding code here from Sandbox for future reference.

EDIT2: [Adding a second example image to show opposing gradients.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXkAU.png) This is mentioned in the comments of Bryce Howitson's answer.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: blue;
}
.column1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="rotated">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Have a look at [linear-gradient](https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'\-moz\-linear\-gradient\%28\-45deg\%2C\%20rgba\%28255\%2C0\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%200\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28255\%2C0\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%2032\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C255\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%2032\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C255\%2C0\%2C1\%29\%2069\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C0\%2C255\%2C1\%29\%2069\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%280\%2C0\%2C255\%2C1\%29\%20100\%25\%29\%3B') instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Paulie_D , that's a good point. I'll edit my question to include the code using the Stack Snippet.

Comment: @ChrisW.  Linear-gradient is actually the end-goal. I intend to add a colour-gradient to each of the different columns, with the gradient going in alternative directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do **A LOT** with a single `linear-background`. The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to transform anything AND it's responsive because it fills the container.

```css
body {
 background: #333;
}

.stripes {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
background-image: 
linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 9%, rgba(224,14,14,1) 9%, rgba(224,14,14,1) 22%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 22%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 45%, rgba(255,89,0,1) 45%, rgba(255,89,0,1) 63%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 63%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 65%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 65%);
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>
```

**Edit #1:**

You can do even more by stacking multiple background gradients on the same element.

```css
body {
 background: #333;
}

.stripes {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
background-image: 
linear-gradient(34deg, rgba(9,9,15,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,0) 70%),
linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 9%, rgba(224,14,14,1) 9%, rgba(224,14,14,1) 22%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 22%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 45%, rgba(255,89,0,1) 45%, rgba(255,89,0,1) 63%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 63%, rgba(2,0,36,1) 65%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 65%);
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>
```

**Edit #2:**
SVG seems like an OK solution to this problem. I like that it's scalable without blurring.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.stripes {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/10307/stripes.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>
```

Unfortunately, this requires editing the SVG file itself to add the rotation. One final option is to use the SVG inline INSIDE the container. We'll use sizing (make it bigger than the container) and absolute positioning to make sure it covers everything when rotated.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.stripes {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.stripes svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top:-50%;
  left:-50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes">
  <svg width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="83.2079305%" id="linearGradient-1">
            <stop stop-color="#E8FF04" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#CD1144" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="86.756968%" id="linearGradient-2">
            <stop stop-color="#3816E3" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#00FF81" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="stripes2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <rect id="R1" fill="#00CEFF" transform="translate(81.836327, 250.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-81.836327, -250.000000) " x="0" y="2.84217094e-14" width="163.672655" height="500"></rect>
        <rect id="R2" fill="#060120" transform="translate(168.982036, 250.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-168.982036, -250.000000) " x="163.982036" y="0" width="10" height="500"></rect>
        <rect id="R2" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" transform="translate(203.441118, 250.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-203.441118, -250.000000) " x="174" y="0" width="58.8822355" height="500"></rect>
        <rect id="R4" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" transform="translate(285.395210, 250.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-285.395210, -250.000000) " x="233" y="0" width="104.790419" height="500"></rect>
        <rect id="R5" fill="#DF0E0D" transform="translate(373.425150, 250.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-373.425150, -250.000000) " x="336" y="0" width="74.8502994" height="500"></rect>
        <rect id="R6" fill="#060120" transform="translate(455.500000, 250.000000) rotate(-360.000000) translate(-455.500000, -250.000000) " x="411" y="0" width="89" height="500"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Bryce, thanks for the great response! You can do alot with the linear-background! However I am looking to add opposing gradients to each "stripe", so I am unsure if this will work out with this approach. I see you can stack multiple background gradients, adding opacity to blend. But I do not see how you can then add a separate gradient to each different stripe.

Comment: When you say "opposing gradients" do you mean a gradient that only interacts with a specific stripe possibly perpendicular to the gradient? Or is it more along the lines of the bottom/left is darker than the top/right?

Comment: @Onomatopoeia I updated my answer to add another gradient crossing the first set. It's not contained to one stripe but matches your example image, I think.

Comment: Hey Bryce, I appreciate the answers. You have been spot-on! Unfortunately I have not asked the entirety of my question in my original post and that is my bad. I have edited my original post to include a second image displaying the "opposing gradients" I am referring to. If you have any idea of how to achieve it, that will be fantastic.. But thanks for improving my linear-gradient knowledge nevertheless!

Comment: @Onomatopoeia No fun in making it simple huh? :-) I have a few ideas about how to solve it but didn't get any time today. Don't give up on it quite yet.

Comment: You answered too quickly, need to test you somehow! I'll hold out hope then :D Thanks!

Comment: @Onomatopoeia that was a good test! How about SVG as a background? Similar to  your original idea with divs in a flexbox but using an element that's made to display as an image.

Comment: Dude, you rock. Thank you so much for not just one, but four different answers to the problem!